# Chain rule in DARTS – Differentiable Architecture Search

Tags: chain-rule, finite-differences, finite-difference-methods

For https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.09055.pdf#page=4 , could anyone help to see how equation (7) is the chain rule result of equation (6) ?

[image: chain rule]

Comment: You should probably set up context for the problem, and narrow the query to a conceptual doubt so it is the easiest to answer.

Comment: @Buraian have a look at https://mythrex.github.io/math_behind_darts/ , I still do not understand why **Evaluating the finite difference requires only two forward passes for the weights and two backward passes for α, and the complexity is reduced from O(|α||w|) to O(|α|+|w|)** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to show that $\color{green}{\text{equation (7)}}$ is the chain rule result of $\color{red}{\text{equation (6)}}$, let's denote $w' = w-\xi \nabla_w \mathcal{L}_{train}(w, \alpha)$

$$\begin{equation} 
\begin{split}
\color{red}{\nabla_\alpha \mathcal{L}_{val}(w-\xi \nabla_w \mathcal{L}_{train}(w, \alpha), \alpha)} 
&= \nabla_\alpha \mathcal{L}_{val}(w', \alpha) \\
&= \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}_{val}(w', \alpha)}{\partial \alpha} \\
&= \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}_{val}(w', \alpha)}{\partial w'} \frac{\partial w'}{\partial \alpha} + \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}_{val}(w', \alpha)}{\partial \alpha} \\
&= -\xi \color{blue}{\frac{\partial (\nabla_w \mathcal{L}_{train} (w, \alpha))}{\partial \alpha}} \nabla_{w'} \mathcal{L}_{val} (w', \alpha) + \nabla_\alpha \mathcal{L}_{val}(w', \alpha) \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}$$

$$\begin{equation} 
\begin{split}
\color{blue}{\frac{\partial (\nabla_w \mathcal{L}_{train} (w, \alpha))}{\partial \alpha}}
= \frac{\partial \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}_{train} (w, \alpha)}{\partial w}}{\partial \alpha}
= \frac{\partial^2 \mathcal{L}_{train} (w, \alpha)}{\partial \alpha \; \partial w}
= \nabla_\alpha (\nabla_w \mathcal{L}_{train} (w, \alpha) )
= \nabla_{\alpha, w}^2 \mathcal{L}_{train} (w, \alpha) 
\end{split}
\end{equation}$$

$$\begin{equation} 
\begin{split}
\color{red}{\nabla_\alpha \mathcal{L}_{val}(w-\xi \nabla_w \mathcal{L}_{train}(w, \alpha), \alpha)} 
&= -\xi \color{blue}{\frac{\partial (\nabla_w \mathcal{L}_{train} (w, \alpha))}{\partial \alpha}} \nabla_{w'} \mathcal{L}_{val} (w', \alpha) + \nabla_\alpha \mathcal{L}_{val}(w', \alpha) \\
&= -\xi \nabla_{\alpha, w}^2 \mathcal{L}_{train} (w, \alpha) \nabla_{w'} \mathcal{L}_{val} (w', \alpha) + \nabla_\alpha \mathcal{L}_{val}(w', \alpha) \\
&= \color{green}{\nabla_\alpha \mathcal{L}_{val}(w', \alpha) - \xi \nabla_{\alpha, w}^2 \mathcal{L}_{train} (w, \alpha) \nabla_{w'} \mathcal{L}_{val} (w', \alpha)}
\end{split}
\end{equation}$$

Comment: Thanks for the proof above for the chain rule section (equation(7)) of the paper. but I am still stucked at equation (8) as in why **Evaluating the finite difference requires only two forward passes for the weights and two backward passes for α, and the complexity is reduced from O(|α||w|) to O(|α|+|w|)** ?

Comment: This probably means two forward passes to evaluate L_train (w^+, alpha) and L_train (w^-, alpha) respectively, both of which are used to calculate the gradient with respect to alpha (two backward passes).

Comment: but in actual sequential coding, how to perform two backward passes TOGETHER ?

Comment: How is [DARTS algorithm](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.09055.pdf#page=4) different from [GDAS algorithm](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.04465.pdf#page=4) ?

Comment: What do you mean by performing two backward passes together?

Comment: Let me rephrase the question, should I split CIFAR-10 into 3 sets for 3 networks respectively ? 
 
1 set for `Ltrain(w+, alpha)` , 
1 set for `Ltrain(w-, alpha)`,
1 set for `Lval()`

Comment: For [this DARTS tutorial](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=http://khanrc.github.io/nas-4-darts-tutorial.html) ,  "First compute `w+` , then get the gradient, then compute `w-` ,  then get the gradient."   <-- I am bit confused about [the coding implementation for w+ and w-](https://i.imgur.com/aNORenf.png)

Comment: `Ltrain(w+, alpha)` and `Ltrain(w-, alpha)` use the same training dataset, you first compute `w+` , then get the gradient of `Ltrain(w+, alpha)` with respect to alpha, **then** do the same thing with `w-`. Does this answer your question?

Comment: ok, same `train` network, but just swapping the weight `w` and then re-compute the gradient ?  Am I getting right that what you meant by gradient is actually the `Ltrain(w±, alpha)` loss (or dL/dz) ?  By the way, any idea on [trick to accelerate the forward pass of DARTS](https://github.com/D-X-Y/AutoDL-Projects/issues/10#issuecomment-782791708) ?

Comment: Exactly, you just change the weight `w` by `w+` (or `w-`) and then recompute the gradient. What I meant by gradient is `Ltrain(w+, alpha)`(or `Ltrain(w-, alpha)`) with respect to alpha. However, I am not familiar with the so-called GDAS algorithm.

Comment: Have a quick look at https://matrix.to/#/!rfNsjPHiCQByBJwJVW:univ-toulouse.fr/$HwHdu1uD9GrA1lfkqgkm73z_BjmLxqWkfItkxCeF8QE?via=laas.fr&via=matrix.org

Comment: Also check out the questions at https://github.com/microsoft/archai/issues/17

Comment: Hi, When you have opened chain rule in 3rd line, why is there need for another term after addition? Since in chain rule we dont have addition. Thanks.

Comment: Is it because it is multivariate chain rule?